# Ember.js - Keeping track of the amount of characters in an Ember.TextArea

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I need a good way to keep track of the number of characters in a textArea, and then display that number on the page.

```
{{view Ember.TextArea
       maxlength='160'
       valueBinding='message'
       autocomplete='off'}}

You have entered {{'messageLength'}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. Got it:

```
messageUpdate: function() {
  if (this.get('message')) {
    console.log(this.get('message').length)
  }
}.observes('message')
```